# GitLab AutoDevops with Oracle artifacts

Tags: java, oracle, maven, gitlab

I've set up a GitLab project that uses Oracle JDBC. The Oracle driver is not in Maven Central Repository, so I've added it on my project manually. That means that, locally, my builds run just fine.

The catch: I want to use GitLab's devops feature. However, my project won't build on GitLab because of this dependency issue, giving me the following error on maven build:

> Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

I want to know how can I supply this dependency so that my project can be built successfully.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

POM.xml contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pom.xml contains a dependency - then you should provide it or delete it.

If you're not trying to understand "maven" way of doing things and just want to make it work - try this "lazy" solution:

```
<repository>
 <id>code-lds</id>
 <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
</repository>
```

Add this repository to your  section. It's a widely-used third-party repository that contains several common artifacts like Oracle drivers and etc.